# Invalid template arguments when using istream_iterator

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using an `istream_iterator` to read all data from an input stream and store it in a string, but for some reason, Eclipse is giving me this error: `Invalid template arguments`

GCC compiles it fine without any warnings or errors, it just seems to be Eclipse giving me the message.

Here's a snippet of my code causing the issue:

```
String fileName = parse.nonOption(0);

// open stream
std::ifstream stream(fileName, std::ios::in);

// read the piped data
stream >> std::noskipws;
std::istream_iterator<char> it(stream); // error on `istream_iterator`
std::istream_iterator<char> end; // error on `istream_iterator`
std::string results(it, end);

// execute it
returnCode = execute(results.data());

// close stream
stream.close();
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: `Invalid template arguments` That's all Eclipse gives me. Like I said, there are no GCC errors or anything.

Comment: @ChrisSmith Eclipses indexer isn't always reliable.